# jCarousel: scroll to first item index of class name

Tags: jquery, indexing, jcarousel

I am using the jCarousel plugin.

What i want to do is when i click on a list item used for navigating the carousel, go to the first index of that class name.  If i click on the **Two** in the `<ul id="bah">`, it should go to the first occurence in the class name *level-2* which in my case would be *jcarouselindex="4"*

I am pretty sure it's to do with this line `jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel('scroll', index + 1);` but i don't know how to change the `index` to the first occurence of the class name.

The only long winded way i can think of doing it is count how many items are in the class so in my case it would be 2 and then in the navigation `<ul>` give each list item an id so the first `<li>` would be `<li id="1">`, the second would be `<li id="4">` etc and then use the id for the index.

Just need to some on the simplest way to do this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'null',
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 4
    });

     // Loop through all images and attach click action
    jQuery("#bah li").each( function(index, element)
    {
        $(element).click( function()
        {
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel('scroll', index + 1);
        });
    }); 
});
```

chghh

```
<ul id="bah">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal">
    <li jcarouselindex="1" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-1"><img src="test/craft-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="2" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-1"><img src="test/conservation-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="3" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-1"><img src="test/contemporary-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="4" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-2"><img src="test/craft-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="5" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-2"><img src="test/conservation-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="6" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-3"><img src="test/contemporary-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="7" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-3"><img src="test/craft-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="8" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-3"><img src="test/conservation-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="9" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-4"><img src="test/contemporary-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>
    <li jcarouselindex="10" class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal level-5"><img src="test/craft-link.png" alt="" width="194" height="74"></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the :gt() selector --> http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```
var idToScroll = $(".level-2:gt(index)).attr("jcarouselindex");

jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel('scroll', idToScroll);
```

or something like that.

regards.